# Move object continuously along y with optional movement along x

Tags: unity, c#, movement, transformation

I am looking for a sensible way to continuously move an object downwards with constant speed while moving left or right by some amount x when the user presses the left or right arrow keys.

Basically, movement should look like this:

```
|
|
V Right Arrow  Key pressed
    |
    |
    |
    V Right Arrow key pressed
        |
        |
        |
        V Left Arrow Key pressed
    |
    |
    |
    V
```

The movement on the x-axis should be smooth, i.e. it shouldn't jump from one spot to the next, but rather move to a **specified** x-coordinate slowly.

What I am having trouble with is moving along the x axis independently of the y-axis.

I have another project where I handled movement towards a certain goal with `Vector2.MoveTowards`

```
void Update()
{
    float step = 1 * Time.deltaTime;
    transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, movementTarget, step);
}
```

I would use this by setting the object's `movementTarget`

But this doesn't lend itself to my current requirements because, when I set the `movementTarget`, I need to specify a y component, which leads the object's velocity on the direction to become zero once the movementTarget is reached, but I need the object to move continuously along the y-axis.

Basically, I am looking for a hypthetical method Vector2.MoveTowards that only takes an x-input.

I'm not sure if I'm making myself clear, so please ask questions if more information is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you use `Mathf.MoveTowards`?

I believe it would be something like this:

```
var position = transform.position;
var step = velocity * Time.deltaTime;

position.x = Mathf.MoveTowards(position.x, targetX, step.x);
position.y = position.y + step.y;

transform.position = position;
```

*Assuming you have a `velocity` vector, and `velocity.x` is positive (so `step.X` is also positive).*

You would, of course, have to pick the `targetX` when you get the input. Perhaps something like this:

```
targetX = (direction + Mathf.Floor(transform.position.x / snap)) * snap;
```

*Where `snap` is the non-zero horizontal step, and `direction` is `-1.0f` or `1.0f`.*

I don't know if you want to impose a minimum and maximum `targetX`. If you do, you might use `Mathf.Clamp`.

Comment: I was able to adapt your solution to make it work, thanks!